# How to DI repository into Type-class?

Tags: dependency-injection, graphql, graphql-dotnet

Need some help here please ...

I'm looking at the example "**graphql-dotnet/server**" where the exposed objects contains just plain properties. But what if I need to resolve a property and get data from a repository, how can I get hold of the respository class in the Type-class?

Example:
The sample has a ChatQuery exposing "messages".

```
public ChatQuery(IChat chat)
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<MessageType>>("messages", resolve: context => chat.AllMessages.Take(100));
    }
```

Instance "**chat**" is the repository here and is serving data (messages) via chat.AllMessages.

Let's say that a message has a list of viewers. Then I need to resolve that list from a repository. This is done in the other example "**graphql-dotnet/examples**" where the "**StarWars/Types/StarWarsCharacter.cs**" has a list of friends and the "**StarWars/Types/HumanType**" has the repository (StarWarsData) inserted in the constructor and can be used in the resolve method for "friends":

```
public class HumanType : ObjectGraphType<Human>
{
    public HumanType(StarWarsData data)
    {
        Name = "Human";

        Field(h => h.Id).Description("The id of the human.");
        Field(h => h.Name, nullable: true).Description("The name of the human.");

        Field<ListGraphType<CharacterInterface>>(
            "friends",
            resolve: context => data.GetFriends(context.Source)
        );
        Field<ListGraphType<EpisodeEnum>>("appearsIn", "Which movie they appear in.");

        Field(h => h.HomePlanet, nullable: true).Description("The home planet of the human.");

        Interface<CharacterInterface>();
    }
}
```

BUT, doing the same thing in the server sample won't work.

```
public class MessageType : ObjectGraphType<Message>
{
    public MessageType(IChat chat)
    {
        Field(o => o.Content);
        Field(o => o.SentAt);
        Field(o => o.From, false, typeof(MessageFromType)).Resolve(ResolveFrom);
        Field<ListGraphType<Viewer>>(
            "viewers",
            resolve: context => chat.GetViewers(context.Source)
        );
    }

    private MessageFrom ResolveFrom(ResolveFieldContext<Message> context)
    {
        var message = context.Source;
        return message.From;
    }
}
```

When I add the chat repository to the constructor in MessageType it fails.

**I'm obviously missing something here; why isn't Dependency Injection injecting the chat instance into the MessageType class in the "graphql-dotnet/server" project?
But it works in the "graphql-dotnet/examples" project.**

Best,
Magnus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use DI you need to pass a dependency resolver in the constructor of your Schema class.  The default resolver uses `Activator.CreateInstance`, so you have to teach it about the Container you are using.

```
services.AddSingleton<IDependencyResolver>(
  s => new FuncDependencyResolver(s.GetRequiredService));
```

`IDependecyResolver` is an interface in the graphql-dotnet project.

```
public class StarWarsSchema : Schema
{
    public StarWarsSchema(IDependencyResolver resolver)
        : base(resolver)
    {
        Query = resolver.Resolve<StarWarsQuery>();
        Mutation = resolver.Resolve<StarWarsMutation>();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/blob/bcf46c5c502f8ce75022c50b9b23792e5146f6d2/src/AspNetCore/Example/Startup.cs#L20

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/blob/bcf46c5c502f8ce75022c50b9b23792e5146f6d2/src/StarWars/StarWarsSchema.cs#L6-L14